# Modifying the django-cms 'add plugin' template on a per plugin basis?

Tags: django, django-cms

The template I'm specifically talking about is the one that is used when a user add's a plugin to a page. Both in the admin area, and when modifying pages directly, it is displayed using an iframe.

The template itself is located cms/templates/admin/cms/page/plugin_change_form.html.

My problem is that I need some javascript to populate a drop down list within the form. All the javascript is run before the iframe is added to the page though, so I thought if I managed to edit the template I can tell the iframe to load some specific js. I can obviously just change the template directly, but that's a bit of an undesirable solution. I would rather keep it within the django application and even better have the js run only on specific plugins.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `change_form_template` on your `CMSPluginBase` subclass, as `CMSPluginBase` is a subclass of `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin`.